# how to initialize class and specify generic type of class by reflection

Tags: java, generics, reflection

### 1, The custom class definition:

```
public class MyClass<T> {

    private T property;

    public MyClass() {
    }

    public MyClass(T property) {
        this.property = property;
    }


}
```

### 2, normal initialization as following is worked:

```
MyClass<String> stringMyClass = new MyClass<>();
stringMyClass.setProperty("hello");
System.out.println("stringMyClass:" + stringMyClass.getProperty());
```

### Requirments:

The requirments is to initialize instance by reflection. The `T` will be specified dynamically. Such as:

```
Constructor<MyClass> con = MyClass.class.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class);
con.setAccessible(true);
MyClass hello = con.newInstance("hello");
System.out.println("property:" + hello.getProperty());
```

but reflection code above is not working, error message as following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: test.mytest.MyClass.<init>(java.lang.String)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at test.mytest.Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

### How to initialize it by reflection ?

Comment: Generic type arguments are not available at runtime. You'll need to pass a `Class` instance for reflection.

Answer (score 2):

the generic type is erased, the constructor parameter type is `Object` instead of `String`

try

```java
Constructor<MyClass> con = MyClass.class.getDeclaredConstructor(Object.class);
```

Comment: There also is no constructor that uses a String.class as an argument. Only a constructor with no arguments and a constructor with the generic (an Object.class by erasure).